# Firebase childs to array (Kotlin)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

Well good morning,

Today my project was to work a bit with Kotlin firebase. Just found a problem I can't seem to find any good documentation on how to store all child's in an array which I then can do a "for" loop on.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? What CAN you do? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Can't find any docs for Kotlin,

Comment: Can you find docs for Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one.

```
 var firebaseDatabase: FirebaseDatabase
            firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

            progressBar.visibility = ProgressBar.VISIBLE
            firebaseDatabase.getReference("players").addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener {
                override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot?) {

                    Log.d("DAta",p0.toString())

                    progressBar.visibility = ProgressBar.GONE
                    if(p0!!.exists()){
                        for (h in p0.children){
                             val player = h.getValue(Player::class.java)
                            photosList.add(player)
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                            Log.d("Data","player is "+player.toString())

                        }
                    }
                }

                override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError?) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity,"Fail to Load Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this library https://github.com/Link184/Respiration

```
@FirebaseRepository(dataSnapshotType = MyModel.class,
    persistence = true,
    isAccessPrivate = true,
    children = {PlanEventRepository.USERS_CHILD, FirebaseRepository.USER_ID, PlanEventRepository.PLAN_EVENTS_CHILD})
public class MyRepo extends FirebaseListRepository<MyModel> {
    static final String USERS_CHILD = "users";
    static final String PLAN_EVENTS_CHILD = "events";

    protected MyRepo(Configuration<MyModel> configuration) {
        super(configuration);
    }
}
```

you can access your list in that way:

```
//MyRepoBuilder is a generated class by annotation processor and can be accedes only after a successful gradle build. 
MyRepoBuilder.getInstance().subscribeToList(new SubscriberRespiration<List<MyModel>>() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(List<MyModel> dataSnapShot) {
          //here is your list =)
      }
  });
```

Kotlin annotation processing is not supported **yet** so you must use java on your custom repositories.

Answer (score 0):

All you want is to loop through all children of a DataSnapShot?
If so, a MutableList should work.
You can try something like this.

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        elements = dataSnapshot.children.toMutableList()
        for (element in elements) {
            //your logic
        }
    }
    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two storage option for Firebase and it wasn't clear in the question which one is used. In our project we are using FirebaseFirestore and saving and retrieving array/list data is pretty straight forward. Save the object as list and just use toObject. For example below querying all the contents of the DB

```
val allEntities = mutableListOf<YourEntityClass>()
val fireStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
val ref = fireStore.collection("yourcollection")
ref.get().addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
            documents.forEach {
                it.toObject(YourEntityClass::class.java).let { entity ->
                    allEntities.addOrReplace(entity)
                }
            }
        }
```